# How do I use a method returning a boolean value with QueryDSL?

Tags: java, querydsl

I have an object `message` and an authenticated `user`. I want to only show a message to the authenticated user, if they are the author or have a specific role.

```java
private boolean isEditor(User user){
    // some complex logic
}

QMessage message = QMessage.message;
User user = getAuthenticatedUser();
boolean isEditor = isEditor(user);
BooleanExpression canRead = message.author.id.eq(user.getId()).or(isEditor); // isEditor is not working here
```

I can't combine the boolean `isEditor` with the BooleanExpression though, is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `boolean` can be converted to a `BooleanExpression` like that:

```java
Expressions.asBoolean(isEditor).isTrue();
```